# Send JVM -verbose output to stderr instead of stdout

Tags: java, command-line, jvm, stdout, stderr

I'm running java with the `-verbose:gc` option to [measure garbage collector behavior](http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc5.0/gc_tuning_5.html#0.0.0.Measurement%7Coutline), but it sends the info to `stdout`, mixing with my program's normal output. How do I tell it to output this info to `stderr`?

Comment: @obvio171: +1... I never thought about it: I'm using some logging framework instead of *System.out.println* so I can easily sort the output to only keep the JVM's output (just some *grep* magic).

Comment: Doesn't the `-Xloggc:file` option send everything to a file?
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[On HP-UX](http://docs.hp.com/en/5992-4687/ch01s25.html)
-Xverbosegc [:help] | [0 | 1] [:file = [stdout | stderr | ]]

[IBMs JDK](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&context=SSCMPC6&dc=DB520&uid=swg21384096&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&lang=en) Any platform that uses the IBM JDK
-Xverbosegclog[:[,,]]

Sun JDK
-Xloggc:file
Report on each garbage collection event, as with -verbose:gc, but log this data to file. In addition to the information -verbose:gc gives, each reported event will be preceeded by the time (in seconds) since the first garbage-collection event.
Always use a local file system for storage of this file to avoid stalling the JVM due to network latency. The file may be truncated in the case of a full file system and logging will continue on the truncated file. This option overrides -verbose:gc if both are given on the command line.